# Associating file extensions with a program

Tags: vb.net, registry, file-association

I get how to do it, and i have been to http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/VBFileAssociation.aspx before. My question is about what doing that does, is it possible to reverse it? What if you do not know where your program will be, and you are just testing it for now? Is there any way for it to "find" your program, or an easy way to edit where it is opened? For that matter, is it possible to tell if the file has been associated already, is it an issue to try and reassociate? Finally, how can you set the .ico file it uses?

Thanks for the help, I know almost nothing about the registry and it confuses me lol...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For brevity, I'm using a fake root key. In practice, replace `Hive_Key` with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` for system default settings, or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` for per-user settings. Either of these keys are allowed to exist, or both. If they both exist, the `HKCU` key takes precedence.

To associate an extension with a file type, you need to set the default value of the extension key (`Hive_Key\Software\Classes\.ext`) with a chosen file type, by setting the default key value.

The actual program launched, as well as other file type details, are found in the file type. File types are noted by what is referred to as a `ProgID` (short for "Programmatic Identifier", which is a more easily readable version of a Class Identifier). ProgID keys are found in `Hive_Key\Software\Classes`, and an example value for this illustration might be `ext_auto_key`.

The ProgID may have a default value, which will be the friendly description of the file type in Explorer (such as, "Microsoft Word Document"). It's up to you to make sure you choose a description that's easily understandable for users.

The ProgID may have a subkey, `DefaultIcon`, which is where the file type icon is stored. That icon path is the default value of that key.

The ProgID key may a subkey, `shell`, which will contain the context menu items on the files, and the program that that context menu item will invoke. Similar to the default value of the ProgID, the default value of the verb key is the text which will show up on the context menu. The default value of this `shell` key has the default verb key name, which is the verb invoked when the user double clicks a file.

These context menu items are `Verbs`. For our example, a verb that opens the file with Notepad would look like this:
`Hive_Key\Software\Classes\ext_auto_file\shell\open\command` with default value `notepad.exe %1`.

This is where you would put your program path. If your program is in the system PATH, as notepad.exe is, you don't *need* to specify the full path. In the more likely case, you'd need to specify the path to your exe. For testing purposes, you can just set it to be your build directory.

You asked how to check this stuff, and this can be done by first inspecting the default value of the extension key to get the ProgID, then inspecting the `shell` subkey of the ProgID key to get default verb, then inspecting `\shell\verb\command` to get the path to the program launched.

It might be enlightening to open `regedit.exe` and browse those registry keys for other file types to get a better idea of how it all works.

Also, the above is all valid if the particular extension is not under control of a program set as default (Default Programs) in the Control Panel. You can check this status by checking of the existence of the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ Explorer\FileExts\.EXT\UserChoice`. If it is, you will need to revoke Default Programs control before your customizations will go into effect. This can be done by deleting that `UserChoice` subkey.