# How can I register "My program files format" on Windows?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Associating file extensions with a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556853/associating-file-extensions-with-a-program)

How can register "My program files format"  on Windows 
to when click on "My program files format"  Open it to My program

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556853/associating-file-extensions-with-a-program

Comment: tag C# is wrong; should be InstallShield

Answer (score 0):

Like UpTheCreek mentioned propably a duplicate. 
Nonetheless: if you want to add your file-type to Windows during setup, you can add your files (and commands) using the FileType option in the standard setup project.