# Java - Creating a new file extension in a program

Tags: java, winapi, file-association

I'm aiming to create a new file extension (possibly more than one) for a program I'm creating. So, after looking around for a bit, I found a number of sources on the subject, listed below, just in case anyone wants to look at them and get the general idea of what I have been looking at.

[Utilising a file association in a Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043029/utilising-a-file-association-in-a-java-application)

[Create registry entry to associate file extension with application in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387769/create-registry-entry-to-associate-file-extension-with-application-in-c)

[Associating file extensions with a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556853/associating-file-extensions-with-a-program/1557440#1557440)

http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B185453&x=6&y=11

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0592.html

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0480.html

Also, note that the Microsoft support one is actually a Visual Basic lesson, but I was just trying to see if there were any similarities in the registry changing.

Most of them generally talk about doing some registry editing so that Windows can recognize the new file and know what to do with it. Then I stumbled upon [this](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/jdic_assoc/) document by Oracle, which claims that you are able to do all of the above with some (seemingly) simple Java code. I figure if it's that easy, though, somebody would have pointed it out already. Also, that document is from 2006. I've got a number of questions, which I understand can be a lot to go through, so if anyone takes time out to answer this, thanks a bunch!

- What's really the best way to go about creating and associating a file type for a Java program?
- If the Oracle method is used, is it done in a completely separate program? I would assume you don't want the file type being created and associated every time the program runs, and from what I've seen, that will actually return errors.
- I want other people (only Windows users) to be able to easily install the program, but I'm on Windows 7 64-bit. Are there any changes I should be aware of to make the association also compatible with 32-bit systems?
- Are the changes easily and completely reversible with either method (i.e. if I just wanted to create a test file extension)?

I couldn't find any extensive sources on teaching how to do this kind of stuff with no previous knowledge of it, so if anyone can't answer my questions, but does have a good source I can look at, that would be nice, too.

Comment: Is this part of an install program?

Comment: I am planning on creating an installer for it, but I have done nothing of the sort yet; I figure I should learn how to do this first.

Comment: Pick an tool that creates install programs and it will deal with all the nitty gritty for you. Installing and uninstalling software is a minefield. You don't want to go there. Get Innosetup or something of that nature to do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it. Will this take care of file associations, as well, or just un/installing?

Comment: Yes, all install packages will do associations for you as well as so much more. Really, don't try to do this yourself, this particular wheel has been well and truly invented already!

Comment: By the way, this question is still up for grabs for anyone who does want to answer the "knitty gritty" part of it.

Comment: It seems however that jdic is still active, if you search for it on google and look at its pages con java.net and java.dev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) is not only a freely available installer that comes from Oracle, but it will also register an apps. interest in file types.  See the [File service demo.](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs) for an example.