# image(png, jpeg) to dll converter

Tags: dll, image-conversion

I need to convert my image file (.pnd, .jpeg etc) to dll file in order to put it in windows registry, kindly help if any one had tried this before.

Comment: Why can't you store the location to a file instead?

Comment: @DanielCasserly window xp does not show image as context menu icon if i do that, i need dll to icon there, it does not accept .icon file as well

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed add the location of an image to context menu using only it's location as an image.

Please see the code to [Resize Images](http://sourceforge.net/projects/resizeimages/) and have a look at how I have created the Windows Registry Keys. It needs to be in the item's route with an Icon key and then it should work. Let me know if you have any issues.

EDIT Please view the fig1 for more info:

fig1
[image]

Comment: when i clicked on "create right click" it gives error "ResizeImagesRegKeys has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience." can you tell me how you added the kay into registry for icon

Comment: Sure it should be in the the HKEYROOT\*\shell\resizeimages under that key there is a key value called icon with a value of the path to the icon. Please check the regedit. It should create right click on initial load.

Comment: Please have a look at the pic to help you out

Comment: It seems that you are using windows 7, if yes then let me tell you that it works for windows 7 but not work for windows xp. .ico file does not get displayed on the context menu in windows xp

Comment: Sorry didn't know it was different. Try following this. Otherwise I can't help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123762/add-menu-item-to-windows-context-menu-only-for-specific-filetype

Answer (score 0):

PNG nad JPEG are image formats, DLL is a dynamically linked (code/programs/functions) library. DLL does **not** contain images, it should contain code to facilitate OS/programs operation.