# Edit right-click context menus in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, registry, contextmenu

I want to add a custom option using registry called `My Button` when I right click an MP3 file
which will launch

```
C:\Program Files\MyApp\app.exe %1
```

The
[following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2123762/add-menu-item-to-windows-)
works great for Windows XP, but doesn't seem to have an effect on Windows 7.

Comment: Actually, I believe it was pretty straight forward. It doesn't matter if it's a MP3 file, or what the name would be. I need a generic answer, so generic question would fit better here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This PowerShell code will do it

```sql
Set-Location HKLM:\software\classes
Get-ItemProperty .mp3 | % '(default)' | % {
  '"C:\Program Files\MyApp\app" "%1"' |
  New-Item -Force "$_\shell\My Button\command"
}
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/47f39b9ecaec1/windows.ps1#L12)