# How to add context menu action for image files in windows explorer?

Tags: contextmenu

I wrote a little program that uploads images to a webserver and puts the url in the clipboard. The program takes the file location form the command line parameters. Example: upload.exe C:\someimage.jpg . I want to put context menu item in windows explorer that appears only when image is selected .jpg, .png and .gif so that I can upload the images easier. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123762/add-menu-item-to-windows-context-menu-only-for-specific-filetype

Comment: I checked... it doesn't work.

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly doesn't work? The custom command does not appear in the context menu? The command appears, but when you click it nothing happens? The command appears, when you click it, the program runs, but the program gets the wrong command line argument? Tell us what registry keys you set. We're not psychic.