# Add a Windows Shell context menu entry for a specific extension (not file type)

Tags: windows, registry, contextmenu

To add a Windows shell context menu, let's say for `.txt` files - if the `.txt` *extension* in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` (or in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`, doesn't really matter) has the default value (*file type*) `txtfile` - you add the command to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\yourcommand` (and the command itself in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\yourcommand\command`, of course) and there you go.

However, let's say the `.txt` *extension* instead has the default value `Notepad++_file`. `Notepad++_file` might be the *file type* for many other *extensions*, so if you add the command to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Notepad++_file`, then this command will appear for every *extension* associated with Notepad++.

So, **the question is**: how can you add a menu entry for ONLY ONE specific EXTENSION, *without changing its file type*, if possible at all?

P.S.: I don't want to just duplicate the file type, because future changes to the original file type won't affect the duplicated one.

Comment: Apparently, the cleanest way these days is the [`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.extension` key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56256624/2075630).

Answer (score 28):

Here you go:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\your custom app]
@="Open with your custom app"
"icon"="C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe,0"
"AppliesTo"=".nfo"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\your custom app\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe \"%1\""
```

The line `"AppliesTo"=".nfo"` does the trick.

Works perfectly on Windows 10.

It works **per file extension, regardless if there is an application associated with that extension or not**. Doing this way it less invasive and leaves a very small footprint in the registry.

Compare to [Add menu item to windows context menu only for specific filetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123762/add-menu-item-to-windows-context-menu-only-for-specific-filetype)

---

Edit:

If you want to apply that command to more than one extension use:

```
"AppliesTo"="System.FileName:\"*.nfo\" OR System.FileName:\"*.log\""
```

Credit: https://superuser.com/questions/183785/windows-7-context-menu-for-folders-if-folder-contains-certain-filetypes

Comment: The ability to apply multiple criteria you provided is a life saver!!

Comment: can I add a shortcut to this menu item, so I can select file and press a shortcut to edit selected file?

Comment: To only check extensions this is simpler: "AppliesTo"="System.FileExtension:=.nfo OR System.FileExtension:=.log"

Comment: PS: "AppliesTo"=".nfo" isn't the same because it include also: file1.nfox, file2.nfoy, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Also you can just do .jpg OR .png OR .gif   etc in the applies to bit