# Add contextual menu to .config files

Tags: windows, registry, contextmenu, custom-contextmenu

I'm currently trying to add a contextual menu (right click menu) on a specific extension : `.config`

I managed to add a contextual menu to all files, unknown files, .jpg, and every other extension I've tried, except for `.config`, and I don't know why.

I even tried to use some external tools to do it. These tools worked for everything I tried, except .config again.

The `.config` register key has a master file type named `config_auto_file`.

I tried to create a `\shell\My_command\command` key on each of them (`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.config and HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\config_auto_file`) with no success. I'm now out of ideas.

An easy, similar test would be `.jpg`, which has a master file type too (`jpegfile`). And it works on this one while doing the exact same thing.

I'm on windows 7 and windows 10.

Thanks for your time on this.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it thanks to [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362892/add-a-windows-shell-context-menu-entry-for-a-specific-extension-not-file-type?rq=1) on stackoverflow.

The "AppliesTo" on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT* worked for me.