# Windows - Add item to the context menu for PNG files for the current user only

Tags: windows, registry, contextmenu

I'm trying to create a program for editing the context menu of specific file/folder types. I was trying to use it to edit the `.png` menu, but the added item isn't showing up.

As far as I'm aware, this *should* add an item with the label "aaa", but it doesn't appear to do anything

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\pngfile\shell\aaa\command]
@="aaa"
```

I've tried replacing `pngfile` with `png` and `.png` with no success.

I can find plenty of posts about doing this in HKCR, but not in HKCU, which doesn't require admin privileges to edit. Well, no posts about in HKCU that work for me for whatever reason.

Bonus question: How would I find where I need to put the command for other file types, like `.jpg`?

EDIT: [Found the answer after a bit more searching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34571628/10720231)

What I have to do:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\aaa]
@="aaa"
"AppliesTo"=".jpg"
```

and for .jpg and .png (Not tested, but this is what it says to do.)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\aaa]
@="aaa"
"AppliesTo"="System.FileName:\"*.jpg\" OR System.FileName:\"*.png\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\aaa\command]
@="aaa"
```

Comment: There are more levels of indirection involved.  Also, this is a computer configuration question, not a programming question.  Once you figure out what your registry needs to look like, a question about the code that makes those changes would be on topic.

Comment: I thought it was on topic because of all the other registry questions on here