# Where are the custom popups for the file explorer stored in Windows?

Tags: windows, registry, microsoft-file-explorer

I'm currently making a little project for my own entertainment - a file explorer. I want to implement these cutom popups with opening options that apps set when right clicking a file in the file explorer.[The custom options like `Git bash here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DGKd.png)
I guess that they are stored somewhere in the registry, but i dont have much knowledge about it. Where in the registry in particular are these things stored?

I tried googling and asking my friends, but i didn't get any good results.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362892/add-a-windows-shell-context-menu-entry-for-a-specific-extension-not-file-type

Comment: thank you! it seems like i found what i wanted