# add menu item for specific file type windows right click menu

Tags: c++, windows, registry, shell-extensions

There is a solution of my question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123762/add-menu-item-to-windows-context-menu-only-for-specific-filetype)

this works file for me if default app is present.
what if there is not default app present for some extension?
is there any way to add item in right click menu of that file extension without making my app as default app for file extension?

Comment: Please summarize the original question in addition to the link

Comment: i want to add iten in right click menu of specific file extension,but i dont want to change default application of that extension.

Comment: Which file extension are we talk about ?

Comment: i want to do it for .zip file extension.

Comment: might get tricky, .zip is over-written by many apps, and the location to make changes at is different.   On my machine with Winrar, it resets the shell key to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WinRAR.ZIP\shell` where I can create custom shell extensions for .zip files.   But if I installed 7zip, it will overwrite the HKCR\.zip default value to no longer point to `HKCR\WinRAR.ZIP`, and I will lose all the custom settings from the WinRAR key.   I guess the ticket would be to read the .zip default value adjusting the location on-the-fly.

Comment: already done by this method.
i am checking default registry of .zip extension and then adding my entry there.
but my actual problem is that if there is no default app present for .zip file extension,how can i add in context menu without making my application as default application of .zip files.

Comment: If by default location you mean this key `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\shell\Open\Command]`,  then we just need create a second command here like `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\shell\MyApp\Command]`.  The Default value should be the command line path + %1 as the argument.

Comment: i can add there.
but if user will install winrar or other software then my menu item will be removed. is there any solution by which i can add my menu item permanently to .zip file extension.

Comment: that could be a good solution but problem is that i dont have admin privilege everytime.

Comment: @kitkat43: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is a merged view of `HKCU` and `HKML`, `HKCU` (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER`) doesn't need special permissions.

Comment: but when i tried to change registry without admin permission i got exception.