# Right clicking a text file using python

Tags: winapi, python-2.7, win32com, pywinauto

I am new to python. I am writing an automation script to right click a text file and then click on a Context Menu Item. Here I am using win32api ans win32con. I am unable to locate a file using win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y)). Is there a way to set cursor on a file without specifying x,y co-ordinates?

Comment: You should always try something yourself and post it. SO is not a free coding service. If anything you could mention what makes you think you could use it, surely there are some functions in the module that you could try.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should append your context menu in windows (by regedit or by menu) and call your script with the filename as argument.

check this : [Add menu item to windows context menu only for specific filetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123762/add-menu-item-to-windows-context-menu-only-for-specific-filetype)

You can then get it with [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) or use the [optparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) module