# How to add item into window's Context menu [only for pdf file and doc file]

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I created one c# application for virtual printer but now I am looking for start my application while right clicking on any .pdf file or any .doc file

in short i want to add item in window's context menu but only for .pdf file and .doc file.

please suggest me how to achieve it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15171/Simple-shell-context-menu

Comment: If my answer helped you please accept this so it doesn't float around next to unanswered questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know what keys to modify/add, see the accepted answer here:
[Add menu item to windows context menu only for specific filetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123762/add-menu-item-to-windows-context-menu-only-for-specific-filetype)

To add the keys using C#, use a **RegistryKey** object

```
string[] exts = {".pdf", ".doc"};
foreach (string ext in exts)
{
    RegistryKey _key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey($"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\{ext}\\shell", true);
    RegistryKey newkey = _key.CreateSubKey("Use Virtual Printer");

    RegistryKey subNewkey = newkey.CreateSubKey("Command");
    subNewkey.SetValue("", "C:\\yourApplication.exe");
    subNewkey.Close();

    newkey.Close();
    _key.Close();
}
```

modified from [How add context menu item to Windows Explorer for folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449316/how-add-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-folders)

Comment: Please quote the relevant sections from your links and be sure to include an explanation in your answers.