# Open Universal Windows Platform (UWP) application via Explorer right click

Tags: registry, win-universal-app, windows-explorer

I already found this:
http://grogansoft.com/blog/?p=1197
And that works great.

But I would love to add direct entry into the main context menu with a verb that pretty much would do that same.

This one claims it's not possible:
[read/write registery key file in uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694059/read-write-registery-key-file-in-uwp)
Is that really true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible since the windows fall creators update. See "[Integrate with windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-extensions#define)". You don't have to mess around anymore with the registry you define your settings in the `Package.appxmanifest`. For example:

```
      <uap3:FileTypeAssociation Name="bla" >
        <uap2:SupportedVerbs>
          <uap3:Verb Id="Edit1" Extended="false" MultiSelectModel="Player">Edit1</uap3:Verb>
        </uap2:SupportedVerbs>
        <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
          <uap:FileType>.banana</uap:FileType>
          <uap:FileType>.foo</uap:FileType>
        </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
      </uap3:FileTypeAssociation>
    </uap:Extension>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. One of the points of the UWP apps is a sandboxed environment, so no registry access.

Comment: I understand the sandbox and registry part, but absolutely not integration with Windows Explorer? That's a bit unfortunate, no?

Comment: By design. No one uses UWP apps on desktop anyway so no problem :)