# How to read registry values in Windows store app?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, windows-10-universal

How we can read/write values in Registry from windows store or universal windows platform app...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read value of a registry key c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232972/how-to-read-value-of-a-registry-key-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read/write registery key file in uwp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694059/read-write-registery-key-file-in-uwp)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it.
Store Apps are working in sandbox and after removal all changes are rollbacked. That means that you can install and remove any number of applications and in result system would be still in same state.
If you want to save some information in settings you can use [ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx)