# Adding context menu item to specific extension via registry

Tags: windows, registry, contextmenu

Let's start off by saying I am on Windows 10 and that i've seen many posts about this subject but none seemed to work for me. Looking at this post has solved some issues but I still need some assistance. [Add menu item to windows context menu only for specific filetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123762/add-menu-item-to-windows-context-menu-only-for-specific-filetype)

What I want to do is add an a specific item to only images (I will start with .jpg) that will say "Upload Image". Here is what I have so far:

- I searched for the default value of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.jpg` which is jpegfile.
- I added this key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\jpegfile\shell\ImagePanel\command`
- I set command default value to my application directory.

After doing all that, the only thing that changed is the context menu shows my application under "Open with" and doesn't actually have its own spot on the context menu.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but you might simply be missing a name for the entry, which has to be stored as default-value of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\jpegfile\shell\ImagePanel` in your case. However, it also didn't work for me – though I tried it with PDF files, where apparently multiple programs vie for defining the `(Default)` value of `...Classes\.pdf".

Comment: Just for reference, I also tried it with other file types – still fails.

Answer (score 7):

Had exactly the same problem, something must have changed in Windows 10.
I finally managed to get it work, here are the keys that worked for me:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.jpg\Shell\

or this one for all the image extensions:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\image\Shell\

for example this is what I used (the first entry is for loading the icon, just the second one is needed to actually create the new menu item):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\Photoshop]
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\\Photoshop.exe,0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\Photoshop\Command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\\Photoshop.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Comment: Might be obvious to some, but it seems you need to use the full path to the executable rather than relying on PATH. For example "python.exe" did not work for me and I had to point the Command to the full path for python.