# Can't add another entry to the explorershell for *.tsv files

Tags: shell, csv, command, windows-10, registry

So I have written a little executable that generates a pdf from a `*.tsv` file and wanted to add a shortcut to the shell of that specific file type.

I already did this with pdf files a while ago and it worked perfectly fine. Followed this tutorial:
[Add menu item to windows context menu only for specific filetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123762/add-menu-item-to-windows-context-menu-only-for-specific-filetype)

This time however the entry just will not show up.

I went to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.tsv` and found the Default entry `“tsv_auto_file”`

So I created a command key in the respective entry
 `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tsv_auto_file\shell\PDF_that\command`

`“C:\Shellextentions\packlist\PDF_packlist.exe” "%1"`

But nothing shows up so I did the same under `CURRENT_USERS` but no change either.

What am I Missing?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow fixed the issue it with changing the default APP (Excel) to Wordpad and back to Excel again. I have no idea why it's working now.