# How to get programmatically access to add a new entry in Context Menu?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, registry

I would add a new entry "Share" in Context menu, so with the right click on a file I would see this new entry "Share" in Context Menu. I tried as in the code below, but method CreateSubKey() throw th exception System.UnauthorizedAccessException saying Denied Access to key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

```
const string MenuName = "*\\shell\\NewMenuOption";
const string Command = "*\\shell\\NewMenuOption\\command";
RegistryKey key = null;
key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(MenuName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree); 
key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(Command, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
key.SetValue("Share", ObjectToStore);
```

I saw something on this [guide](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10104/Add-a-context-menu-to-the-Windows-Explorer) but I think that on .NET2.0 it was different

Comment: I Solved the probem running a separate exe with administrator rights which set key. In this way the request of right is asked only once @Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need (local?) administrator permissions for this. Try executing your app as administrator.
If this works you have two choices:

Method one is to require administrator rights to run your application - *not the best idea*.
Method two would be a second (command line) project which has only one purpose, creating those registry keys. This app requires administrator permissions. And you can run this application (`Process.Start(...)`) from you main application.

To force admin-permissons in your application add an `app.manifest` / manifest-file to your visual studio project and uncomment this line `<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

The hole file should be looking like this (there are more default entries in the app.manifest visual studio generates for you)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        <!-- <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" /> -->
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Then go to project settings, application and in the lower screen under manifest you choose your app.manifest file. Rebuild. Done.

Comment: Where possible, creating applications that require elevated privileges should be avoided. In this case, adding to HK_USERS would likely be more appropriate.

Comment: @FedericoRizzo Some more details would be nice... What have you tried and whats happening?

Comment: It surely *is* the better solution (in your case), but sometimes admin-permissions are required. Then this is one way to go. I've tested my post (again), works for me.

Comment: Now I understand that Context menu can be edited with HK_USER so I have to find another solution. I have to use HK_CLASSES_ROOT. I will try better your solution if I can't find nothing

Comment: It works. I have only to understand as to avoid the permission request every time when the app is launched

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding to HK_CLASSES_ROOT, your application will have to be running with elevated privileges. You should ideally be keeping any changes to HK_USERS which should have the same sub keys

Comment: Please a moment. Are you sure that with HK_USER I can edit Context Menu? @DiskJunky

Comment: This post has a more detailed How To guide; https://stackoverflow.com/a/2124396/1838819