# How does the .gdoc format work?

Tags: file, google-docs, file-extension, file-format

If you work with Google Docs your first file format is .gdoc / .gsheet / .gwhatever

What I want to understand is, how this file format works. When you open a .gdoc you basically open the browser and go to a specific URL. So is a .gdoc just a .html-file with a changed file extension?

I would like to build something similiar: A rich-text-editor which saves the content in my own file format, that you can download and if you open the file, the browser opens and links to a specific URL.

BTW: I opened a .gsheet in a text editor and found this source code:

```
{"url": "https://docs.google.com/a/test.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=01234567898765432123456789&usp=docslist_api", "resource_id": "spreadsheet:0A12345B678HJK9TZPL9078767"}
```

*Changed the URL a bit ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.gdoc` and `.gsheet` files don't contain html, but `JSON`. These extensions are usually linked to the Google Drive application, which just reads the file and opens the URL with your standard browser.

If you're going to implement something like this yourself, you can go the same route: let the user install a program that handles your own files and start e.g. the browser.

Another way is to just use standard shortcuts; or use can use html files (maybe with another file extension if you link this extension to the standard browser) which just redirects to your target url.

---

in response to your comments:

to create a simple shortcut, you'll have to generate a file with the following content:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=your.url.com
```

and save it as `YourFileName.YourExtension.url`. Note that the "real" file-extension is `.url`. When saved to disk, windows explorer will usually hide the `.url` part (regardless of the *Hide known file types* setting). When the user starts this file, it will just open `your.url.com`. Chrome provides an API to create and save files client-side, but I don't know about other browsers. Probably you'll have to use a third-party library for creating the files (if you want to do this client-side).

Note this is a Windows-only solution. I don't know how you would handle this on Mac OS.

Comment: Thx but I don't understand the last paragraph of your answer: what do you mean with standard shortcuts? and how can I link the costum file extension with the standard browser? this is the most interesting part for me :D

Comment: @Retador I mean a simlpe shortcut like those you can create in the windows explorer. Shortcuts don't have to point to a program, they can also contain a URL. To set a default program for a file extension, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789319/how-to-make-a-c-sharp-application-work-as-the-default-program-for-certain-files) question. The default browser is usually the one which is assigned to htm/html files.

Comment: For clarification here a scenario: Someone uses my iFrame-based rich text editor. Then he clicks save – the document is saved online in his user account. Now he has the option to download his file – he will actually download a .html file but instead of .html I want to append .abc. On his desktop the user doubleclicks his example.abc-file, his standard browser opens and he gets directed to a webpage showing his document. How do I tell the user's computer without an additional app that he is supposed to open the .abc file in the standard browser? This has to work on Mac OS as well as on Windows.

Comment: You can't without an additional app. In case of google docs, the google drive application handles this for you. Since you don't want an additional application, I think using a simple shortcut would work best for you. I'll update my answer with an example.