# How to manually register ClickOnce file associations after installation?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, registry, clickonce

Microsoft's [ClickOnce deployment system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) offers an easy-to-use file association manager which is [built into the Visual Studio deployment process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892924.aspx). Developers can add up to 8 file associations which will automatically be associated with their application when the user runs the ClickOnce installer.

I'd like to take it one step further, though: **I want to allow users to manually add or remove *additional* file associations after installation from within my application.**

I have two motivations for accomplishing this:

- I won't "force" additional file associations on the user, which is how file associations through ClickOnce deployments are handled.
- Users can add or remove their own unique file associations at their leisure.

#### The tricky part: Directly associating a filetype with an executable is not compatible with ClickOnce deployments

Unlike traditional Windows applications, ClickOnce applications are not launched directly via their executable. Instead, they are launched via a special `.appref-ms` shortcut which handles the ClickOnce magic behind the scenes (automatic updates, locating the executable files in an obfuscated directory in `%LOCALAPPDATA%`, etc).

If a ClickOnce-deployed app is opened directly via its executable, automatic updates are disabled and ClickOnce-specific methods will no longer function. Because of this, traditional registry file associations are not possible for my use case.

#### How Visual Studio handles ClickOnce file associations

The image below demonstrates Visual Studio 2010's built-in ClickOnce file association manager. This information is stored in the application's .manifest file and is added to the Windows registry upon installation.

[image: VS2010's ClickOnce File Association Manager]

I've done some digging through my registry and have identified several entries made by the ClickOnce installer to associate filetypes with the ClickOnce deployed application.

An example registry key for a ClickOnce filetype association I found in my registry:

`rundll32.exe dfshim.dll, ShOpenVerbExtension {ae74407a-1faa-4fda-9056-b178562cf98f} %1`

Where `{ae74407a-1faa-4fda-9056-b178562cf98f}` is a GUID used in several other locations in the registry for the associated application.

**My goal is to learn what information must be added to the registry (programmatically) to manually associate files with a ClickOnce deployed application.**

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387769/create-registry-entry-to-associate-file-extension-with-application-in-c (C++, but the concept should be the same). The accepted answer has some very useful information.

Comment: You could also benefit from using an application like ProcessExplorer to see specifically what is being set during a ClickOnce install.

Comment: perhaps the GUID is the identifier of the current clickonce install directory. did you try searching for this GUID in the registry?

Answer (score 2):

You can figure out the registry keys to be added, using Windows Sysinternals Process Monitor (Previously known as RegMon).

Capture Events when you install your app using ClickOnce with default file associations. It will record all the registry operations (lots of them).

You would need to use some filters to easily identify the registry keys.

Comment: This suggestion proved to be helpful to me. A basic tutorial for Process Monitor can be found at [http://www.howtogeek.com/school/sysinternals-pro/lesson5/all/](http://www.howtogeek.com/school/sysinternals-pro/lesson5/all/).

Answer (score 2):

Ok so after experiencing the same problem and doing some serious digging I think I have a solution. Evan Wondrasek was on the right path with the rundll command, and I was able to get the following working in a test environment.

Essentially Uri Abramson was right that the Guid in the rundll.exe command is a reference to the clickonce application but it doesn't appear anywhere else in the registry. What it references is actually the other Keys in `HKCU\Software\Classes`.

To make the file reference work you first need a `ProgID` for your application. To my knowledge this can be whatever you want, or whatever you would normally set it to in the ClickOnce publishing menu in Visual Studio.

You will also need to create a new Guid, and know the contents of your Application Reference (.appref-ms) file.

For my example I will use the following:

```
ProgId: FASERVER.TestApp
Guid: ce6b2c69-ec54-4182-a87f-74c5dfe1a03e
AppRefFileContents: http://SomeAddress.SomeDomain/TestApp/TestApp.application#TestApp.application, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=df31b9b884b9be10, processorArchitecture=x86
```

Please use your equivalent of the above values in the following code.

To start, make a new registry key under `HKCU\Software\Classes` called `FASERVER.TestApp`
 with the following strings:

```
(Default) = SomeFileType
AppId = TestApp.application, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=df31b9b884b9be10, processorArchitecture=x86
DeploymentProviderUrl = http://SomeAddress.SomeDomain/TestApp/TestApp.application
Guid = {ce6b2c69-ec54-4182-a87f-74c5dfe1a03e}
```

Once you have set these values create two new subKeys `shell` and `shellex`.

Set the `(Default)` value of `shell` to `open`. Then create a subKey of `shell` called `open`, and a subKey of `open` called `command`. Set the `(Default)` value of `command` to the following:

```
rundll32.exe dfshim.dll, ShOpenVerbExtension {ce6b2c69-ec54-4182-a87f-74c5dfe1a03e} %1
```

Create a subKey of `shellex` called `IconHandler` and set its `(Default)` value to `{ce6b2c69-ec54-4182-a87f-74c5dfe1a03e}`

Navigate to `HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID` and create a new key `{ce6b2c69-ec54-4182-a87f-74c5dfe1a03e}` with the following strings:

```
(Default) = Shell Icon Handler For Tif File
AppId = TestApp.application, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=df31b9b884b9be10, processorArchitecture=x86
DeploymentProviderUrl = http://SomeAddress.SomeDomain/TestApp/TestApp.application
IconFile = YourIconFile.ico
```

Note: Your icon must be in your ClickOnce project.

Now create a subKey under `{ce6b2c69-ec54-4182-a87f-74c5dfe1a03e}` called `InProcServer32` with the following values:

```
(Default) = dfshim.dll
ThreadingModel = Apartment
```

Lastly we need to link the previous keys with the file associations we desire. To do this navigate to `HKCU\Software\Classes` and do the following for each desired file extension.

Set the FileExt strings as follows:

```
(Default) = FASERVER.TestApp
AppId = TestApp.application, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=df31b9b884b9be10, processorArchitecture=x86
DeploymentProviderUrl = http://SomeAddress.SomeDomain/TestApp/TestApp.application
Guid = {ce6b2c69-ec54-4182-a87f-74c5dfe1a03e}
```

That's it! You should be done.

Please note this will not set your application as the default program for that file type but will simply add a "ClickOnce Application Support Library" entry to the "Open With" menu.

Hope this works for someone other than me and sorry for the long winded example.

Answer (score 1):

What about the Assoc command?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184082

---

assoc /?

Displays or modifies file extension associations

ASSOC [.ext[=[fileType]]]

.ext      Specifies the file extension to associate the file type with
  fileType  Specifies the file type to associate with the file extension

Type ASSOC without parameters to display the current file associations.
If ASSOC is invoked with just a file extension, it displays the current
file association for that file extension.  Specify nothing for the file
type and the command will delete the association for the file extension.

---

File associations can be machine level or user level - 
Generally, stuff in the HKCR area is for machine-level file associations.
Stuff in the HKCU/Software/Classes area is per-user stuff the user has customized (or you customized for them).
Something like "assoc" will work on XP, 7, and probably Win 8 (althought i haven't used this cmd on win 8 yet).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually register the file association, it's none of ClickOnce's business. you can manually add keys to registry to setup file association. And if you want to remove the association which is set by clickonce, just remove the registry key.

```
    private static void SetFileAssociation(string icon, string application, string openArg, string extension , string progId , string description )
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("-----Create File Association-----");
        RegistryKey classesKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Classes", true);
        classesKey.CreateSubKey(extension).SetValue(string.Empty, progId);
        RegistryKey progKey = classesKey.CreateSubKey(progId);
        if (description != null)
        {
            progKey.SetValue(string.Empty, description);
        }
        if (icon != null)
        {
            progKey.CreateSubKey("DefaultIcon").SetValue(string.Empty, icon);
        }

        progKey.CreateSubKey(@"Shell\Open\Command").SetValue(string.Empty,
            application + openArg);
        Trace.WriteLine("-----Finish File Association-----");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unlike traditional Windows applications, ClickOnce applications are not launched directly via their executable. Instead, they are launched by a special `.appref-ms` shortcut which handles the ClickOnce magic behind the scenes (automatic updates, locating the executable files in an obfuscated directory in `%LOCALAPPDATA%`, etc). If a ClickOnce-deployed app is opened directly via its executable, automatic updates are disabled and ClickOnce-specific methods will no longer function. Because of this, traditional registry file associations are not possible for my use case.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The application doesn't launch it's exe directly. There's a solution for your issue : you do NOT publish your app's exe, you just create a new exe which is a wrapper of your basic exe and what it does is just launch your basic exe. Then you include your basic exe as a file to your ClickOnce deployment. After completing these, you can just manually add registry to your basic exe. But you need to pay attention to your app's updates. You should also update the real exe path in the registry after the ClickOnce update.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:
You can associate with shortcut of ClickOnce application located in:

```
C:\Users\[Your username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\[Program folder]\[Shortcut name]
```