# Create Associativity between file extension & application?

Tags: c++, windows

I am creating an application using Qt. The files saved from my application have their own file format & extension. I want to associate this file format with my application.
So, when a user double clicks say myfile.ext then the OS should automatically run my application (how to specify its path?) & pass path of file as an argument.

I have only used Windows until now so I am talking in terms of it. I dont know  how other OS's behave. Any guidance for the same would be helpful?

PS: Even though I am using Qt which apparently has no special functionality to do what is asked here (AFAIK), it would be awesome to know how to do this in standard C++.

Comment: I think you can find the answer in the answers to this post: [Create registry entry to associate file extension with application in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387769/create-registry-entry-to-associate-file-extension-with-application-in-c?rq=1)

Comment: a few pointers there: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/4810/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows see the MSDN page ["File Type Handlers"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144146%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for how to register file type handlers.

On many popular Linux desktops, so-called `.desktop` files are used to define what application to use for opening a file. See the ["Desktop Entry Specification"](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) for the structure of those .desktop files. They are quite simple really, changes are you can just take an existing file from any of the popular Linux desktop environments (e.g. [KDE](http://www.kde.org/)) and modify it a bit.

Comment: @Cool_Coder: Oops, you're right. Fixed - thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: thats an amazing link! Answers a lot of my questions in mind.

Answer (score 1):

It's a function of the OS, not of the C++ language.
You'll need to figure it out on each platform you are supporting.

Comment: What is sad about it? You cannot expect that language as C++ would support features of every OS it can run on.

Comment: Not if you think about it: Your program isn't running yet, so nothing in your code can do anything about it. It has to be an OS feature.

Comment: @jnovacho, actually I wanted do this during the first run of my application; since my application does not have a installer.