# How to specify "Type of file" property

Tags: c#, windows, installation, file-type

I have my application and database file that goes with it. Databases have extension ".myDb".
Without the application, the database file will show ".myDb File" in Windows Explorer (Properties -> Type of file).

However, after I install the application, I associate file type ".myDb" with my application and now in Windows Explorer it says "Open with MyApp".

How can I change this to say something specific like "MyApp project" without the "Open with" part?

Answer (score 0):

These associations happen in the registry.

A simple search brought the following results :

[Create registry entry to associate file extension with application in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387769/create-registry-entry-to-associate-file-extension-with-application-in-c)

[How to associate a file extension to the current executable in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-to-the-current-executable-in-c-sharp)

[Associate File Extension with Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681878/associate-file-extension-with-application)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but these only tell me how to associate my file type with my application. I've already done that. I just need to change this text, and I don't know how.