# Adding my app to Explorer Context Menu

Tags: windows, contextmenu, explorer

I am looking into adding a link to my app to the Explorer (windows) context menu. I've looked around for how to do this.  I have done it and it works just fine by adding a key to

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell
```

Searching the web I found this:

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens
```

But this seemed so simple (the *\shell method)

```
http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/
```

HOWEVER no app(on my computer) does this (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell) and I wonder if this is not the best solution. I think most apps I have use an inproc dll to work with Explorer. I don't know if that's why they don't go with the *\shell method or there's some other reason why this is not the best way. I could convert my app to an inproc dll if I had to but that seems unnecessary to me if I can use the *\shell method.

OF COURSE the big reason is that I have to logged in as Administrator to do this (*\shell). I was thinking of adding a separate little file that the admins would run. Which seems like a better way in a corporate environment (or any where users are not logged in as admins).

Comment: Adding to `*` adds you for all files. Most apps do not register for all files; they register only for the file types they support.

Comment: Mine handles all files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add menu item to windows context menu only for specific filetype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123762/add-menu-item-to-windows-context-menu-only-for-specific-filetype)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2069565/1569 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/2124396/1569 etc, been asked many times

Comment: Yes, but, there are apps like Winzip and Notepad++ which work with any file type and they don't use \*\shell from HKCR.