# Run compiled python .exe with a file as input

Tags: python, input, executable

So I made a program in Python and compiled it to `.exe`. This works fine.
What I want is to be able to double click files I created (say with text in them) and open those files with the `.exe` I compiled and then do something with the files as input.

I figured one way to do this might be to at least get the exact location of the file that is being opened with the `.exe` so as a first test something like this:

`.exe` file:

```
get_location = dirname(realpath(My_Clicked_File))
print get_location
```

The file clicked will be some random extension so `.test` or something I made up.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I expect if you make your .exe the default opening program for a particular file type, and double click a file of that type, then its name and path will be available in `sys.argv`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create registry entry to associate file extension with application in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387769/create-registry-entry-to-associate-file-extension-with-application-in-c)

Comment: I will look into the other post and return if that helped me. Thanks (I couldn't have found that file with my knowledge on what to search :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've associated your file extension with your exe, when you double-click on the file its full file path will be passed as the first argument, which you can get from `sys.argv` in your script.

Comment: That actually gives the path of the .exe and not the file doubleclicked (tried that first).

Comment: Did you check the second argument?

Comment: On second thought Yes this is the answer. It just is not the first argument from sys.argv[0] but it is the second so sys.argv[1]. Thanks!