# Why is DefaultIcon registry setting not working (Python/winreg)

Tags: python, windows, registry, winreg

The code below is intended to set the default icon and default application for a file type based on what I have been able to learn about Registry settings. I can see that the changes are being made using regedit, but the information for the files with that extension are not changing. Any suggestions on how to do this?

```
import os.path
import _winreg as winreg

G2path="Z:\\Scratch\\GSASII"
G2icon = 'c:\\gsas2.ico,0'
G2bat = os.path.join(G2path,'RunGSASII.bat')

gpxkey = winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,r'Software\CLASSES\.gpx')
#gpxkey = winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, '.gpx')
iconkey = winreg.CreateKey(gpxkey, 'DefaultIcon')
winreg.SetValue(iconkey, None, winreg.REG_SZ, G2icon)
openkey = winreg.CreateKey(gpxkey, 'OpenWithList')
g2key = winreg.CreateKey(openkey, 'GSAS-II')
winreg.SetValue(g2key, None, winreg.REG_SZ, G2bat)

winreg.CloseKey(iconkey)
winreg.CloseKey(g2key)
winreg.CloseKey(openkey)
#winreg.CloseKey(gpxkey)
winreg.FlushKey(gpxkey)
```

Answer (score 1):

Clues for solving my icon problem were found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127427%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. I needed to:

1. set a value for the key I was creating and
2. trigger an update of the shell to see the changes.

This code does work to get an icon displayed:

```
import os.path
import _winreg as winreg

G2path="Z:\\Scratch\\GSASII"
G2icon = 'c:\\gsas2.ico'
G2bat = os.path.join(G2path,'RunGSASII.bat')

gpxkey = winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, '.gpx')
winreg.SetValue(gpxkey, None, winreg.REG_SZ, 'GSAS-II project') # what was needed!
iconkey = winreg.CreateKey(gpxkey, 'DefaultIcon')
winreg.SetValue(iconkey, None, winreg.REG_SZ, G2icon)    
winreg.CloseKey(iconkey)
winreg.CloseKey(gpxkey)

# show the change
import win32com.shell.shell, win32com.shell.shellcon
win32com.shell.shell.SHChangeNotify(
    win32com.shell.shellcon.SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, 0, None, None)
```

To also get an application associated with the extension, I needed to do more. This helped: [Create registry entry to associate file extension with application in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387769/create-registry-entry-to-associate-file-extension-with-application-in-c)

Note that as suggested in the link, I am using HKEY_CURRENT_USER, since that avoids requiring admin privs.

```
import _winreg as winreg

G2bat = "Z:\\Scratch\\GSASII\\RunGSASII.bat"
G2icon = 'c:\\gsas2.ico'
gpxkey = winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,r'Software\CLASSES\.gpx')
winreg.SetValue(gpxkey, None, winreg.REG_SZ, 'GSAS-II.project')
winreg.CloseKey(gpxkey)

gpxkey = winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,r'Software\CLASSES\GSAS-II.project')
winreg.SetValue(gpxkey, None, winreg.REG_SZ, 'GSAS-II project')

iconkey = winreg.CreateKey(gpxkey, 'DefaultIcon')
winreg.SetValue(iconkey, None, winreg.REG_SZ, G2icon)
openkey = winreg.CreateKey(gpxkey, r'shell\open\command')
winreg.SetValue(openkey, None, winreg.REG_SZ, G2bat+" %1")

winreg.CloseKey(iconkey)
winreg.CloseKey(openkey)
winreg.CloseKey(gpxkey)

import win32com.shell.shell, win32com.shell.shellcon
win32com.shell.shell.SHChangeNotify(
    win32com.shell.shellcon.SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, 0, None, None)
```