# Editing the Registry for `.mp3` file

Tags: c++, registry

Editing the Registry for `.mp3` file, with refrence from answer given here :
[Create registry entry to associate file extension with application in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387769/create-registry-entry-to-associate-file-extension-with-application-in-c/2069565#2069565)

i wrote the following code in c++ , to add `open_wihtNewAPp` in contex menu for .mp3 files.

```
Registry::SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Classes\\mp3file\\shell\\open_wihtNewAPp\\command", nullptr, "C:\\Users\\Devansh\\Desktop\\GUI.exe \"%1\"");
    Registry::SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Classes\\.mp3", nullptr, "mp3file");
```

But the option is not getting added in context menu.
I checked in `regedit` as well, the key has been added successfully.

EDIT:
snapshot of context menu on .mp3 
[image]

Comment: Does it work if you do the changes in regedit, without C++? Does it work if you reboot after changing it?

Comment: C++ did exactly what you told it to do: make a registry key. You may want to ask [over at superuser](http://superuser.com/) because you're likely to get better targeting on the real question of: "Why doesn't my registry key work?".

Comment: @deviantfan unfortunately No, it doesn't work that way either when i change manually, I tried both way through code and Manually.

Comment: @deviantfan i thought of inserting registry edit, snapshots as well, but then it would be too many snapshot so i chose to ask this way.

Comment: @Devansh Well, then your key/value is just wrong, as user4581301 said too. It's not a programming problem anymore, ask at Superuser.

Comment: well thanks, I shall try at super user.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything in the linked question that looks like your approach. Computers are rather exact. If they look for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\mp3file\shell\open\command`, then do not expect `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\mp3file\shell\open_wihtNewAPp` to work. Even a spelling error as small as "wiht" part is already too much, let alone the entire `_wihtNewAPp` part.

Comment: from what I understood, open_wihtNewAPp is text that will shown in context menu and spelling error shouldn't matter there.

Comment: i will be more than happy if just correcting spelling could make the registry work.