# Install Shield 2015 le - File extensions ignored - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installshield, file-extension

I am hoping somebody has dealt with this.

Install Shield 2015 le edition, the file extensions section does absolutely nothing in Windows 10.

I figured this was due to existing defaults,  but even after removing all references in the registry,  on installation of an installer with new file extensions set it does nothing not even so much as a registry key added.

This is confirmed on several systems.

The only information I could find from Flexera was that it will not replace an existing association.   Is there anywhere else other than the registry that we need to look to clear out extension data?

This is obviously a bug in install shield but Flexera say no.

Is there a better way to add an extension during install?

Thanks.

Comment: I have recognized the same problem here with the IS2015LE. Now I will give it a try to register the extension directly in the regestry, described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387769/create-registry-entry-to-associate-file-extension-with-application-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work around is to execute a batch file as an action.

Put the file in the application root (with the executable).

```
FTYPE MyFileType=%~dp0Executable.exe "%%1"
ASSOC .MyExt=MyFileType
```